# Invalid Token - Login Issue

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, cache, security-token

Joomla 3.4.1

I was hoping somebody could briefly explain this for me. I am not that familiar with tokens, sessions or cache.

My site was working fine with no issues however I decided to enable the "System-Cache" plug-in and set "Use Browser Caching" to Yes. Since doing this I have been unable to login to the website, each time I receive a blank page with an error `Invalid token`.

I have since disabled this plugin, cleared cache and all is working well again, no login issues. So am I not able to use browser caching? Perhaps I should be doing something else? I couldn't find any definitive answers to this question, lots of people suggesting different solutions.

Tested with Chrome and IE if that matters.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a lot of known (yet unfixed) issues with the System Cache plugin **and** Use Browser Caching when trying to login. A lot of people have reported an Invalid Token.

There are some other things that could be causing this. So try the following (some may not apply to your specifically)

- Disable apache's `mod_cache`
- Disable the server Memcache feature
- Set *Use Browser Caching* to **Off**
- Clear all cache and cookies from your browser

If you require caching, I'd recommend going with a dedicated caching extension. Perhaps [JotCache](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jotcache).

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @Lodder his info is really helpful! Hopefully Joomla will improve on the whole cache thing as there does seem to be a lot of frustration surrounding it.